# How to convert from Javascript to Python API for FeatureCollection in GEE?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I have a JS Code which runs well:

```
dataset = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');
elevation = dataset.select('elevation');

var means_of_tea = tea.map(function(field){
  var elevation_mean = elevation.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: field.geometry(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });
  var slope_mean = slope.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: field.geometry(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });
  return field.set({elevation:elevation_mean, slope:slope_mean});
```

I tried to convert the code to python:

```
def map_fc(field):
  elevation_mean = elevation.reduceRegion({
      'reducer': ee.Reducer.mean(),
      'geometry': field.geometry(),
      'scale': 30,
      'maxPixels': 1e9
  })
  return field.set({'elevation': elevation_mean})
teawithmean = tea.map(map_fc)
```

But gives the error:

```
<ipython-input-36-e999072d4723> in <module>()
      9   })
     10   return field.set({'elevation': elevation_mean})
---> 11 teawithmean = tea.map(inmap)

17 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ee/__init__.py in init(self, *args)
    397           raise EEException(
    398               'Invalid argument for ee.{0}(): {1}.  '
--> 399               'Must be a ComputedObject.'.format(name, args))
    400         else:
    401           result = args[0]

EEException: Invalid argument for ee.Reducer(): ({'reducer': <ee.Reducer object at 0x7f3b4699e4a8>, 'geometry': ee.Geometry({
  "functionInvocationValue": {
    "functionName": "Feature.geometry",
    "arguments": {
      "feature": {
        "argumentReference": null
      }
    }
  }
}), 'scale': 30, 'maxPixels': 1000000000.0},).  Must be a ComputedObject.
```

I've read the google guide for converting form JS to python but had no idea why this happen. Is the error duo to wrong syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Python EE API, use Python named argument syntax instead of dictionaries for arguments.

```py
  elevation_mean = elevation.reduceRegion(
      reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry=field.geometry(),
      scale=30,
      maxPixels=1e9
  )
```

Note that a property name is not a named argument, so `set()` works the same way as in JavaScript; you can use a dictionary or not, but do not use `=`.

```py
return field.set({'elevation': elevation_mean})
# or
return field.set('elevation', elevation_mean)
```

Comment: Code runs with no error. But the result is different. With JS in code.GEE when I try to **elevation_mean.aggregate_array('elevation');**  the output is a List of dict with 'elevation' as key and value of elevation stored there. But in python, the result is a lot different,  including the coordinates of each feature in FC which is strange.

Comment: @masoud You'll need to give more detail. Please post a new question and include a **minimal example** that is runnable but demonstrates the different result.

Comment: While writing new post, I realized that I should use **getInfo()** after `elevation_mean.aggregate_array('elevation')` when printing the result. I used to just _print(List)_ in GEE code editor without getInfo() that always worked for me.